# Как найти НОД нескольких чисел?

Tags: python, алгоритм

> Дано n целых чисел. Требуется найти такое наибольшее целое число, на которое делятся все эти n чисел.

У меня есть код для нахождения нод двух чисел, но как реализовать нахождение нод нескольких чисел?

Answer (score 2):

```
import math
math.gcd(2, 6, 12)  # 2
```

> [`math.gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) Changed in version 3.9: Added support for an arbitrary number of arguments. Formerly, only two arguments were supported.

До версии 3.9, но выше 3.5 можно скомбинировать так:

```
math.gcd(3, math.gcd(6, 12))  # 3
```

Пример:

```
from math import gcd
from functools import reduce

reduce(gcd, [3, 12, 6, 18])  # 3
```

Для версии ниже 3.5:

```
from functools import reduce

def gcd(a, b):
    return gcd(b, a % b) if b else a

reduce(gcd, [3, 6, 12])  # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Берем первые два числа. Ищем НОД (назовем его `nod`). Берем третье число, ищем НОД  к нему и `nod`. Повторять, пока числа не закончатся.