# Нахождение НОД нескольких чисел на Python

Tags: python-3.x

Всем привет! Занимаюсь изучением языка Python. Никак не могу решить задачу с академии яндекса по нахождению НОДа нескольких чисел :(. Задача из раздела "Вложенные Циклы". Суть заключается в следующем:

*"В одном из местных НИИ часто требуется находить наибольший общий делитель (НОД) нескольких чисел. Вам уже доверяют, так что вновь пришли с этой задачей.
Формат ввода
В первой строке записано одно число NN — количество данных. В каждой из последующих NN строк записано по одному натуральному числу.
Формат вывода
Требуется вывести одно натуральное число — НОД всех данных чисел (кроме NN)"*

Но, решить надо, как я понял, без использования списков, словарей, готовых функций (типа math.gcd()) и т.д., т.к. тема вложенные циклы идет после тем:
*Ввод и вывод данных. Операции с числами, строками. Форматирование
Условный оператор
Циклы.* Т.е. предполагается, что я владею только перечисленными выше темами.

Даже не знаю с какой стороны подойти. Конечно, можно использовать уже готовую функцию math.gcd(), но очень хочется понять алгоритм решения. Спасибо всем откликнувшимся ☻

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Напишите программу, которая для двух положительных целых чисел находит НОД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473786/); [Как найти НОД нескольких чисел?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294201/)

Comment: @Nowhere Man Первый линк - неудачные ответы

Comment: `но очень хочется понять алгоритм решения` - Неужели он нигде не описан, и здесь на сайте нет реализаций?

Comment: Есть реализация только для 2х чисел, либо с использованием уже готовой функции math.gcd(). Другого я не нашел.

Comment: Считаете для двух, потом для результата и третьего, и так далее. Если получилось 1, можно остановиться.

Comment: Да, можно все числа загнать например, в список и через функцию reduce и функцию, которая ищет НОД двух чисел решить данную задачу. Но, вопрос в том, возможно ли ее решить имея знания только про операции с числами, про условные операторы и циклы?

Comment: Ну зачем список? Прочитали число - обработали, найдя gcd с текущим значением

Comment: Да вот и не пойму, как по одному числу обрабатывать. Ведь НОД можно же найти минимум у 2-х чисел.

Comment: Нод присвоить первое число. Нод присвоить gcd  нод и очередного числа. Повторять

Answer (score 1):

В общем, получилось все-таки решить без использования функций и готовых решений...

```
n = int(input())  # вводим сколько будет чисел
second_number = 0  # второе число для расчета НОДа на первом цикле

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    first_number = int(input())
    # Ищем НОД по алгоритму Евклида (делением)
    while first_number != 0 and second_number != 0:
        if first_number > second_number:
            first_number %= second_number
        else:
            second_number %= first_number
    # Перезаписываем вторую переменную num2 НОДом.
    # На следующем цикле будем искать НОД нового введенного числа и полученного НОД
    second_number += first_number

print(second_number)
```

Либо можно с функциями...

```
 from functools import reduce


 def gcd_multiple(num1, num2):
     '''
     Функция считает НОД num1 и num2 по Алгоритму Евклида (делением)

     Параметры:
         num1 - первое число
         num2 - второе число

     Return:
         НОД чисел num1 и num2
     '''

     while num1 != 0 and num2 != 0:
         if num1 > num2:
             num1 %= num2
         else:
             num2 %= num1
     return num1 + num2


 n = int(input())  # вводим сколько будет чисел
 list_num = []  # в этот список будем добавлять числа, введенные пользователем
 count_num = 0  # счетчик для выхода из цикла, когда закончатся числа

 for i in range(n):
     num = int(input())
     list_num.append(num)
     while count_num < len(list_num):
         gcd_multiple_result = reduce(gcd_multiple, list_num)
         count_num += 1

 print(gcd_multiple_result)
```